# Is it possible to prevent launchd running a missing task on wake?

Tags: sleep-wake, launchd, macos

I have a `launchd` task configured to run once an hour using the `StartCalendarInterval` key to set specific times at which the task will run.

However, the default behaviour of this is that, when an interval is missed (i.e- computer was asleep) the task will immediately run at the next available opportunity (i.e- on wake).

Is it possible to disable this behaviour in my plist file?

I haven't found any obvious key(s) for controlling this, and the only other thing I can think of is to check the current time in the task itself, but this means duplication of timing behaviour (set the time in the plist, and then check it in the task itself).

Comment: The short answer is no. If you want your "task" to only run at prescribed times then consider using `cron`.

Comment: I had a similar problem with launchd causing simultaneous parallel executions of a single task, resulting in output to a single file with duplicate interleaved lines.  This was NOT caused by a missed interval, but by a single StartCalendarInterval one minutes after the computer woke from sleep by the System Preferences Energy Saver Schedule.  I also had to resort to 'cron' get a single output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## shell script wrapper

`launchd` has no built-in method for limiting tasks that missed their start time. Your idea to use a shell script wrapper to evaluate the desired time and actual time is a reasonable approach.

For Power Manager, we provided a [`drift`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/api-elem-drift.html) duration for exactly this purpose. Drift lets the user state how long after a missed trigger time the event is permitted to run.